# PHP MVC file structure

Tags: php, directory-structure, application-design

How should I structure directories in mvc design pattern in PHP so that I could be able to use the same model and controllers in 'backend' and 'frontend' with different views.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

I am trying to build a website using PHP as server side language and dediced to use MVC design pattern. In my localhost (xampp) I created folder structure like below:

```
htdocs -- mvc 
           |---- controllers
           |---- models
           |---- views
           |---- library
           |---- system-admin (backend)
               |___ controllers
               |___ models
               |___ views
               |___ index.php (single entry point - backend)
               |___ .htaccess
           |---- index.php (single entry point - frontend)
           |---- .htaccess
```

I tried to implement basic 'login-system' and created 'Login_Controller' and 'Login_Model' Files.

**I GET CONFUSED**

How can I be able to use 'Login_Controller' and 'Login_Model' from both  `backend` and `frontend` while using seperate views for each. What do I mean is , the url for admins to login will be :
`http://localhost/mvc/system-admin/login/` and the url for site users to login will be :
`http://localhost/mvc/login/`.

I am designing the `backend` using `twitter-bootstrap` framework but the design of `frontend` will be done by some other who may not use the framework that I have used so I need different views. Both `backend` and `frontend` will share the files from `library`. Some Models and Controllers are also shared (such as Login_Model and Login_Controller) and some are not (such as Dashboard_Model and Dashboard_Contoller will be used only in backend I think) .

**WHAT I NEED**

I need some guid on structuring my directories and judgement on my current file structure. I have never used any design pattern (except `singleton` :-) ) nor any PHP frameworks so I am not able to make any decision on how to structure files.

Comment: `controllers/admin , controllers/users` . Then you can put something in your library to check the role of the user then redirect on the corresponding controller. For scripts and css you can put it in `mvc/assets`

Comment: Backend and frontend are separated modules so they should have separated `controllers`, `views`, etc. folders. But you can have common `models` and `libraries`.

Comment: How can I check the role before login. If someone is registerd as admin then he will go to `http://localhost/system-admin/login` and others will go to `http://localhost/login` for login. My task is to show different login pages (views) using the same controller (Login_Controller). and how?

Comment: Thankyou for your comment , I will try with multiple controllers as you both suggested, thanks.

Comment: Here's a hint: don't put in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` files that you do not expect users to open. Most of your application should be located outside `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Also, model is not a class. Model is a layer.

Comment: @tereško thanks for comment but I could not really understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Lekhnath , do you not know what `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is? Or was the "model part" the confusing bit?

Comment: @tereško I think normally `public_html` are the document roots, but in localhost (xampp) I have no idea. Models and Controllers both are confusing me. As many things are new to me (the `application` directory, the `bootstrap.php` router, `public` , `library`, `autoloader` and recent the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`) , I think they are bit tricky to me. Please keep me alive by providing some tips and some tutorials with `backend` `frontend` `themes` using PHP MVC ..

Comment: Then start with [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16356866/727208) of materials. Also, MVC has nothing to do with themes.

Answer (score -1):

for general i would set up your MVC Project the following:
Folder Structure
    /frontend/controllers
    /frontend/models/
    /frontend/views/
    /backend/[The same as Frontend]
    /public/ with Index.php (here the User starts)
    /libary/ for your Libarys
With this structure the User can not access directly the views oder models.