# PHP MVC structure where to put own classes

Tags: php, model-view-controller, structure

I just started taking a look at the MVC pattern.
My question is:

Where would I put my other class files (Database, User, Logger, Mailer, etc)? Should I create a new directory for them, e.g. `libs`?

Should I instantiate the classes in the `Controller` inside the `model` function?

```
<?php

class Controller {
    protected function model($model) {
        require_once('../app/models/'. $model .'.php');

        return new $model();
    }

    protected function view($view, $data = []) {
        require_once '../app/views/'. $view .'.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you gave up on studying MVC and instead decided to learn Laravel. Well .. whatever pays the bill, I guess,  I case if you ever get an urge to start learning about MVC again, you could go through lectures and other materials listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16356866/727208

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where would I put my other class files (Database, User, Logger, Mailer, etc)? Should I create a new directory for them, e.g. `libs`?

Putting them in separate files since they all provide different functionality should be fine. There is no difference in your directory naming - as long as it matches the naming conventions of your project or general (probably, even better).

> Should I instantiate the classes in the Controller inside the model function?

**No.** As far as I see it, the flow could be similar to:

1. The `index` file receives the request and initiates a new `bootstrap` instance
2. `bootstrap` sets the throwable handler and the router
3. `router` then calls the respective method basing on the request method and uri provided by matching against a set of routes
4. The matching `route` initializes all the components of the MVC triad and the callable method. The components (`Model` layer, `View` layer, and `Controller` layer) are passed to the method called by the `router`. In my case, I call the class `FrontController`, the method `init`.
5. Basically, the `init` is the place where the MVC triad is actually made. `Model` layer is responsible for business logic, persistence, etc. It is important to note that `Model` is not a single file or class (the same for `View` and `Controller`). Both `View` layer and `Controller` layer consult the `Model` layer to do the respective actions. `View` layer's mission is to manage the output, for example, decide wether the output will have `Content-Type` of `application/json` or `text/plain`, or which `Template` to render. Also, `Views` are not `Templates`, which are meant for displaying the data. Note here, `Views` ask the necessary data directly from the `Model` layer; there is no interaction with the `Controller` layer whatsoever. Finally, `Controller` layers steps in when there is a need for *interaction*, for example, a user submits a form, the respective `Controller` filter the input and calls the method from the `Model` layer.

Comment: Downvoted because: 1. advocating for computation in a constructor; 2. use of static classes;3 controller does not handle communication (the viewmodel in MVVM does); 4. your suggestion about making a controller in a god-object is really disturbing

Answer (score 1):

As MVC has three major parts, I'd recommend (and noticed that almost all frameworks on the market do so) to create a directory of each of the three components, and place the classes in the appropriate directory.

As regarding the other components, `Database` is a utility and can be placed for example in a `lib` directory, `User` is a model and can go to the `model` folder, and `Logger`/`Mailer` can also go to the lib folder. These are examples and not something to strictly follow.

As for instantiation, each `Controller` can define the list of `models` and `libraries` it depends on and have the `MVC` framework handle the initialisation of those objects. You'd follow the `dependency injection` pattern this way.