# Is MVC an OOP concept?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

As the title indicates, my question is if Model-View-Controller pattern belongs to object-oriented programming.

I have been programming with PHP 5 with models, views and controllers using a framework, but a friend is telling me that is possible to use this pattern also in functional programming?

Is he right? thanks for your usual explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better answers to your questions than this  You have to fully Understand the MVC

[How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000)

**And**

[MVC for advanced PHP developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356420/mvc-for-advanced-php-developers/16356866#16356866)

Also have look on this Scala functional PL

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/485